Angular 17 works with Webpack or Vite? (Polyfills)
When I create an Anglar17 application I see when I launch it that in the console it displays “Vite connected”.
But at the same time the @angular-devkit/build-angular package seems to depend on webpack.
I tried to install @angular-builders/custom-webpack but I read somewhere that it is not supported by Angular 17 (sorry I can't post the link I don't remember, I've looked through hundreds of web pages and just spent over 11 hours trying to add polyfills with no luck).
On the other hand I also read that Angular does not allow the configuration of Vite. Is it correct ?
If I summarize with Angular 17 it would be impossible to use polyfills because it does not allow the personalized configuration of Webpack or that of Vite. Am I wrong ?
